# I want to display the text within the <a href> tag, in the page that it redirects to

Tags: php, html

The page I refer to, with the anchor tag, should display what I write within it.
For eg:

```
echo "<a href='".$question."'>$question</a>"
```

should display the text in `$question` , as a text in the page that it links to.

How can i achieve this using php or html?

PS: I'm new to both php and stackoverflow! So any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Pass data to URL as GET parameter:

```
<a href="example.com?q=<?php echo urlencode($question); ?>"></a>
```

In PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q'], ENT_QUOTES);
}
```